# Delete Line From File After Echo (or other condition is met)

Tags: php, terminal, fgets, file-put-contents

I have a **list.txt** file which I get its contents with **fgets**. I then echo the contents of each line in the **list.txt** file in a while loop until **fgets** reaches end of file. Now, I want to delete a line after it has been echoed in the **lists.txt** file after it has been echoed.

I've tried putting the lines in another file **(list2.txt)** and then using the ideas of **put_contents** but i've been unsuccessful in doing that and in a few other things i've thought of to try. I can't help but feel like i'm overthinking it.

```
$list = fopen("list.txt","r");
while(! feof($list))  
{
try{ 
$lines = fgets($list);
echo "$lines \n";
// I don't need to delete the lines here
} 
catch (Exception $e)
{
echo "Error \n ";
// I want to delete the lines here
exit;  
} 
}
fclose($list);
// I want to delete the lines here
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Use `file()` to read all the lines into an array. Delete the lines from the array, then write it back to the file with `file_put_contents("lists.txt", implode('', $array));`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally do this using **file()** and **for** loop but couldn't with **fgets** and **while** loop. Barmar's comment above pointed me in the right direction but implode wasn't cutting it for me.

```
$list = file('list.txt'); // opens list.txt into an array
$listcount = count($list); // counts the number of lines/array elements  
for ($x = 0; $x <= $listcount; $x++) //for loop to echo and delete each line
{
echo "\n $list[$x]\n"; 
unset($list[$x]); // deletes the lines that's just being echoed
file_put_contents("list.txt", $list); // puts the remaining contents of 
                                    //the array back into list.txt file
}
```